# How do I create multiple instances of a ViewModel in C# using Ninject while avoiding code smells?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection

There are two parts to my question.

The first is, how do I create multiple instances of a `ViewModel` class using Dependency Injection? Example;

I am creating a `WPF` application using the `MVVM` pattern, `Dependency Injection` with `Ninject` and an `SQLite` `Database` with `EntityFramework.Core`. It is structured like so;

- I have a `View`, say `Tier1View` that is bound to a `ViewModel`,
  `Tier1ViewModel`.
- Within `Tier1View` is an `ItemsControl` with a
  `DataTemplate` of `Tier2UserControl`, the `ItemSource` for the `ItemsControl`
  is an `ObservableCollection<Tier2ViewModel>` effectively `Binding` the
  `Data Context` for each `Tier2UserControl` to an instance of
  `Tier2ViewModel`.
- In turn each `Tier2UserControl` has an ItemsControl of
  `Tier3UserControl` bound to `ObservableCollection<Tier3ViewModel>`.

Since the collections of Tier2 and Tier3 ViewModels are of uncertain size at compile-time, as they rely on Tables in the Database for initial Data and can be changed during run-time, this removes the possibility of using Constructor injection in so crude a way as this example (to the point where I am ashamed to even consider it).

```
public Tier1ViewModel(ITier2ViewModel firstInstance, ITier2ViewModel secondInstance, ...)
{
    Collection.add(firstInstance);
    Collection.add(secondInstance);
    ...
}
```

How do I create multiple instances of a dependency within the same class? It has previously been suggested that I use a Factory (which is supported by Ninject) on a question I asked about passing variables to an injected dependency and I have created a successful implementation of this.

```
Collection.Add(IViewModelFactory.CreateTierNViewModel());
```

and injecting the factory into the Tier above's Constructor.

However this leads to the second part of my question.

Each instance needs to be identifiable in the collection - therefore `Run-Time Data` must be passed to each instance "Created".

According to [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) article, using a factory adds complexity and maintainability to an application. Something I am trying to avoid in my goal of better understanding programming. It also makes the point that Run-Time Data should not be injected into the construction of objects, but passed in via methods.

The `Tier3ViewModels` are going to be distinguishable by containing unique `Entities` from the `SQLite` Database (They are in fact the `View Models` of those `Entities`), since the `Entities` can only be known at `run-time`, is the correct approach to create an instance of a dependency (for lack of knowledge about other ways, using the factory) and then have a method within that `ViewModel` that takes my entity as a parameter (or better yet an abstraction of that entity such as `IEntityType`)?

```
var instanceOf = Factory.CreateViewModel();
instanceOf.AddingMethod(IEntity);
```

I hope some of this is translatable! Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a data object must be passed on your ViewModel then declare those in the constructor.

```
public class Tier2ViewModel
{
   public Tier2ViewModel(Tier2Entity tier2Entity) { //... }
}
```

From there you can create `Tier2ViewModel` without using dependency injection and just create them manually within your `Tier1ViewModel` class.

```
public class Tier1ViewModel
{
   private void LoadTier2()
   {
      //TODO: load tier2Entities using EF
      //TODO: foreach tier2Entity, create new Tier2ViewModel
      //TODO: add each Tier2ViewModel instance to ObservableCollection<Tier2ViewModel>
   }
}
```

But if you really want to use dependency injection then you're on the right track of using a `Factory` class. But instead pass the `Entity` object on the `CreateViewModel` method.

```
public interface ITier2ViewModelFactory
{
   Tier2ViewModel CreateViewModel(Tier2Entity tier2Entity);
}
public class Tier2ViewModelFactory : ITier2ViewModelFactory
{
   public Tier2ViewModel CreateViewModel(Tier2Entity tier2Entity)
   {
     return new Tier2ViewModel(tier2Entity);
   }
}
public class Tier1ViewModel
{
   private readonly ITier2ViewModelFactory _tier2ViewModelFactory;
   private void LoadTier2()
   {
      //TODO: load tier2Entities using EF
      //TODO: foreach tier2Entity, call _tier2ViewModelFactory.CreateViewModel(tier2Entity)
      //TODO: add each Tier2ViewModel instance to ObservableCollection<Tier2ViewModel>
   }
```

As you can see, the factory added another layer of abstraction which to me is unnecessary for the sake of using DI to create an instance. Personally, I would only use the `Factory` pattern if the instantiation of the object will involve complex logic that needs to be tested.

Comment: This sort of answer my question, in that Factories make the most sense and work! But doesn't this create a coupling in the class with the factory? Which is what we are trying to eliminate with DI?

Comment: No it doesn't. The `Tier1ViewModel` only depends on the interface `ITier2ViewModelFactory` and not the factory implementation itself. So you can mock the factory interface when you need to unit test `Tier1ViewModel`.